# docker proxy passwords clear text?

Tags: docker

Am I missing something with docker?  I ask this because after reading docs for over an hour, i realize that not only does this thing want me to put my proxy server user/password **in clear text** into an environment variable, but it also wants me to put it into the DockerFile itself, again, **in clear text!!!** so the image can get to it?

Am i missing something here?  please tell me that someone has a more secure way to do this.  I am getting this ready for a security risk assessment from our auditors, and this alone is enough to kill the technology.  Please tell me there is another way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Passwords should not be backed inside the image by putting them inside the Dockerfile.

**For Production:**

Docker swarm is the production orchestration tool for Docker. Docker swarm allows you to handle sensitive information using [Docker secretes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/). The secretes are
encrypted and strongly secure. When Deploying a stack file, secretes are linked to the service. They are created separately and cannot be accessed as plain text.

**For Development:**

Docker secretes can be used outside of docker swarm (i.e in dockercompose), however in that case they are not secure. This is reasonable since local development environments do not require such strict security.

**Conclusion:**

Docker sercetes are the docker solution for handling sensitive data. When used in Docker swarm, secretes are secure and cannot be viewed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends for what you need the proxy.

If it is only during build time, you can use [build-args arguments](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables-build-arg), which will leave no trace in the built image.

If not, you can use [docker swarm secrets](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/) to find any secret at runtime.